# Python Invoke - Can't find any collection named 'tasks'!

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, invoke, pyinvoke

I did the getting started on 
[Python Invoke](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/)

```
from invoke import task

@task
def build():
    print("Building!")
```

The expected output is

```
$ invoke build
Building!
```

However, my output is

```
$ invoke build
Can't find any collection named 'tasks'!
```

I have no idea why.

Something amazing is, once I invoke in the virtualenv, then I can build without virtualenv.

```
> mkvirtualenv myenv
> invoke build
Building!
> deactivate myenv
> invoke build
Building!
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to documentation your file containing task should be named tasks.py. Make sure you are running build from the same directory as tasks.py, too

Comment: Thanks, I got it! I misnamed it task.py :P

Comment: I came here because this file: "https://www.pyinvoke.org/faq.html#invoke-split-from-fabric" should probably say that "fabfile.py" is not "tasks.py".

Comment: is it possible to run invoke <task_name> from different directory

Comment: Yes, you can point `--search-root` to your directory to pick up tasks from there.

Answer (score 6):

You can also rename `tasks.py` to the name of your choice and can run it with `'-c'` option.

Suppose below is your simple py file named as `'invoke_testing.py'`

```
from invoke import task

@task
def check_config_files(c):
    print("Hey I am Checking configurations")
```

You need to run through command line like this: for example to list down the availabe tasks

```
invoke -c invoke_testing --lists
```

which outputs:

```
Available tasks:
  check-config-files
```

p.s. `'_'` has been replace with `'-'` in the function name
and if you need to run a specific task, it has be run with name as listed in the list.

```
invoke -c invoke_testing check-config-files
```

I got this reference from this source [Python Invoke](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/issues/151)

Let me know if anyone gets more information around this.